# NSTableView Rendering "Upside Down"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Well, this is quite the interesting problem.  I've laid out an NSTableView (view-based) which is wired to a custom cell loaded from a nib (in `-initWithCoder:`), yet the cells themselves render upside down.  But this isn't just any traditional upside down, the frames of the UI objects are literally "flipped", so any element that was positioned at {0,0}, would then be positioned at {0,120} with right-side-up text.  Perhaps some images would make a better explanation:

In the XIB
[image: The Cell in the XIB]

Now in the table

[image: And in the table]

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you've got flipped coordinates, as described here: [flipped scrollview](http://www.poweredbytim.co.uk/programming/nsscrollview-top-left-pinning-and-isflipped/).

Can you check the `isFlipped` property of all your views and cells and make sure it's NO? (`isFlipped` is a property of NSGraphicsContext.)

And here's the official guide on coordinates: [origin lower left vs upper left](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html)

Comment: Oh wow, that's brilliant.  It must have been set to yes accidentally.